# Flutter Riverpod: Filter rebuilds with StateNotifier and .select()

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, riverpod

This is my current state management solution

```dart
class UserState {
    final int id;
    final String name;
}

class UserNotifier extends StateNotifier<UserState> {
    UserNotifier() : super(User(1, 'Pero Peric'));
}

final userNotifierProvider = StateNotifierProvider((ref) => UserNotifier());
```

I want to rebuild my UI only when the name changes not the id!

Riverpod provides a way to do this [link](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading/#using-select-to-filter-rebuilds) but I can't get it working with my StateNotifier.

I would write it like this but it isn't working like this.

```dart
// inside Consumer widget
final userName = watch(userNotifierProvider.select((value) => value.state.name));
```

Can you refactor my code to work or propose another solution?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not working"? Is it rebuilding even when the name didn't change? Or is it not rebuilding at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/riverpod/RootProvider/select.html), "this method of listening to an object is currently only supported by useProvider from hooks_riverpod and ProviderContainer.listen".

Try to create another provider, which you can use in UI.

```
final nameProvider = StateProvider<String>((ref) => ref.watch(userNotifierProvider.select((user) => user.name)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```dart
class UserState {
  UserState({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
  });

  final int id;
  final String name;
}

class UserNotifier extends StateNotifier<UserState> {
  UserNotifier() : super(UserState(id: 1, name: 'Pero Peric'));
}
  
final userNotifierProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<UserNotifier, UserState>((ref) => UserNotifier());
```

In consumer,

```dart
final userName =
        watch(userNotifierProvider.select((value) => value.name)); // value is the state
```